# How to remove HTML tags in a string Handlerbar.js Using regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, handlebars.js

I have a string like

```
var string =`<div><b>Test data</b></div><div><div>Invalid DateTime Only YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss is allowed</div></div><br><div><div>Invalid DateTime</div>`
```

Remove those HTML tags from the string using regex in Handlebar.
My code looks like

This **DISPLAYVALUE** is my exact String, I have to replace the HTML tags here

```
<span title="{{{this.DISPLAYVALUE}}}"> {{strip-scripts this.DISPLAYVALUE}}
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove-ico right" data-filter-val="{{{this.DISPLAYVALUE}}}" datacolname='{{@root.currentColName}}'>
<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
</a>
</span>
```

Excepted Result:-
Test data Invalid DateTime Only YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss is allowed Invalid DateTime

Comment: U need to extract the string value to be shown as a result of the html code ?! U can use js to change the inner html

Comment: Looks like the string is missing a closing div tag.

Comment: yeah! but it's not an issue I just want to show the string, not the tags

Comment: Can you just use string.replace in js?

Answer (score 1):

There are HELPER methods that you can use directly in handlebars templates.For example you can create a seperate handlebars helper js file like below;

```
    (function() {
    Handlebars.registerHelper('stripScripts', function(param) {
        var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig
        return param.replace(regex, "");
    });

})();
```

Then you can simply call this method in your template like;

```
<span title="{{{this.DISPLAYVALUE}}}"> {{stripScripts this.DISPLAYVALUE}}
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove-ico right" data-filter-val="{{{this.DISPLAYVALUE}}}" datacolname='{{@root.currentColName}}'>
<i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JS:

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "<div><b>Test data</b></div><div><div>Invalid DateTime Only YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss is allowed</div></div><br><div><div>Invalid DateTime</div>"; 
    var res = str.replace(/<div>/g, "");
    var res = res.replace(/<\/div>/g, "");
    var res = res.replace(/<b>/g, "");
    var res = res.replace(/<\/b>/g, "");
    var res = res.replace(/<br>/g, " ");
    console.log(res);
}
```